# ngTable filter column with array data

Tags: angularjs, arrays, filter, ngtable

I try to find first help on the official page of [ngTable](http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-filtering-basic) but without results.

I want to fill the data table with my array of objects (see example below)
It is realyl simple to sort and filter by text or number (on the columns "name" and "remark")
But I want also show one column of the data "users" which is a array of user objects. My table is showing the data by adding all users into one column. 
But for now I'm not able to sort or filter these data column of array.

Maybe I have to add a custom filter by filter-options, but I have now idea how to make this possible.

It would be also great if I can preset the filter of "users" in the ngTableParams of my controller - like "filter: {'users': 'A'}" (to show only items where one or more users with firstname = "A" is in users list.

Hope someone can help me on this.
Thx, Jorgen

DATA:

```
this.data = [{
  name: 'Test A',
  remark: 'test A',
  users: [
    {_id: 1234, firstname: 'A', lastname: 'B'},
    {_id: 2345, firstname: 'B', lastname: 'C'},
    {_id: 3456, firstname: 'C', lastname: 'D'},
    {_id: 4567, firstname: 'D', lastname: 'E'},
  ]
},
{
  name: 'Test B',
  remark: 'test B',
  users: [
    {_id: 1234, firstname: 'A', lastname: 'B'},
    {_id: 5678, firstname: 'E', lastname: 'F'},
    {_id: 3456, firstname: 'C', lastname: 'D'},
  ]
},
{
  name: 'Test C',
  remark: 'test C',
  users: [
    {_id: 5678, firstname: 'E', lastname: 'F'}
  ]
}];
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table ng-table="myCtrl.tableParams" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-vmiddle" show-filter="true">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in $data">
      <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'" filter="{'name': 'text'}">{{item.name}}</td>
      <td data-title="'Users'">
        <span class="m-r-10" ng-repeat="user in item.users">{{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}}</span>
      </td>
      <td data-title="'Remark'" sortable="'remark'" filter="{'remark': 'text'}">{{item.remark}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
this.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
  sorting: {name: 'asc'}
},
{
  data: this.data
});
```

https://embed.plnkr.co/7sGrv7IpUzCXDN1USeyX/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it In Controller:

```
angular.forEach(this.data, function (obj, idx) {
    obj.filterOnUsers = [];
    obj.filterOnUsers = $filter('filter')(obj.users, { firstname: obj.name });
});
```

check this [Angular Filter Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: Thank you for fast reply. 
I'm searching for an solution by using ngTable technique.
I do not want to modify the array before, because this can bring wrong pagination of the data table.

maybe it is a way to use [custom filters](http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-customize-algorithm) But I have no idea how to for array entries...